# How to divide two fields and get an average

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elastic 6.5

I need to divide two fields together and then get an average value.

Example mysql that I am trying to recreate:

```
SELECT avg(field1/field2)
FROM table
WHERE field1 > 0 && field2 > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my task with the query below:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": { 
    "match_all":{}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "average": {
      "avg": {
        "script": {
          "source": "(doc['field1'].empty || doc['field2'].empty || doc['field2'].value < 1  ? null : doc['field1'].value / doc['field2'].value)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you are looking for using [Script Fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html).

I've created sample mapping, documents, the query and the response for this use case which are mentioned below:

### Mapping

```
PUT myindex
{  
   "mappings":{  
      "mydocs":{  
         "properties":{  
            "field1":{  
               "type":"long"
            },
            "field2":{  
               "type":"long"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

### Sample Documents:

```
POST myindex/mydocs/1
{
  "field1": 0,
  "field2": 0
}
POST myindex/mydocs/2
{
  "field1": 20,
  "field2": 20
}
POST myindex/mydocs/3
{
  "field1": 40,
  "field2": 20
}
POST myindex/mydocs/4
{
  "field1": 40,
  "field2": 0
}
```

### Query Request

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "_source":"*",
   "query":{  
      "match_all":{  

      }
   },
   "script_fields":{  
      "average":{  
         "script":"long a1 = 0l;long a2 = 0l;if(params._source.field1==null){a1 = 01;} else {a1 = params._source.field1}if(params._source.field2==null || params._source.field2<0){ a2=0l} else {a2 = params._source.field2}return a2 > 0? (a1/a2) : 0;"
      }
   }
}
```

Note that you can modify the above logic accordingly to fit your use case of averaging only if `fields > 0`

### Response

```
{
  "took": 12,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "mydocs",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "field1": 20,
          "field2": 20
        },
        "fields": {
          "average": [
            1
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "mydocs",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "field1": 40,
          "field2": 0
        },
        "fields": {
          "average": [
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "mydocs",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "field1": 0,
          "field2": 0
        },
        "fields": {
          "average": [
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "mydocs",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "field1": 40,
          "field2": 20
        },
        "fields": {
          "average": [
            2
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What you are looking for in the above response is the `average` field.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I kept having a problem with the formatting of the script when running it in Kibana, so I didn't get to see the result.

Comment: Hey @Crixus, not a problem. Next time do mention in question that you'd want to run query in kibana. Would've created query accordingly. Your answer has a condition missing. Other than that looks good. Go ahead and accept your answer.

Comment: which condition am I missing?

Comment: Current condition is `doc['field1'].empty || doc['field2'].empty || doc['field2'].value < 1` where you didn't mention `doc['field1'].value < 1` check. in your solution.

Comment: @KamalI I see where you are coming from. The reason why I didn't have this extra condition is because 0/1=0. Is there a performance benefit to having this extra check?

Comment: I mentioned that because in your question, you have mentioned it. And I assume you only have positive integers and not negatives. Even so, I amuse myself at times. I think it's great what you have. As for performance benefit, I don't think that makes a difference, but I'd write that logic because we should code for humans to understand. Some of us are still humans ;)